# How can I scrape data which is not visible in source page?

Tags: web-crawler, jsoup

basically i want to crawl codechef problems of specific tag but in this
[link](https://www.codechef.com/tags/problems/bfs) all the content of this page is dynamic, so now i am helpless, please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scrape HTTPS javascript web pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561950/how-to-scrape-https-javascript-web-pages)

Answer (score 0):

We use [jBrowserDriver](https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver) in StormCrawler, this should allow you to programmatically navigate the site and extract what you need

Comment: Thanks for your reply, As i am begginer in crwaling so can you please tell me that how to use that method you suggest to extract data in android studio @Julien

Answer (score 0):

Try using selenium, it will allow you to load the page in real time, from there you get take the page source, then pass the page source (html) into jsoup.